# How to write factories for models with has many through association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, associations, factory-bot, minitest

I have three models with has many through association 
User model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_projects
  has_many :projects, through: :user_projects
end

Project model

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_projects
  has_many :users, through: :user_projects
end

UserProject model
class UserProject < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
end

How to create factories for these three models

Comment: With factoryBot?

Comment: you can use factory bot gem together with rspec to write test cases. If you're question is intended on how to create test suite.